# How to locate a method quickly in Rails' API docs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For instance, I want to find the constructor of `ActionController::RoutingError` at http://api.rubyonrails.org/. I typed `ActionController::RoutingError` or `RoutingError` in the search box, nothing got returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad example. See the source:

```
  class RoutingError < ActionControllerError #:nodoc:
    attr_reader :failures
    def initialize(message, failures=[])
      super(message)
      @failures = failures
    end
  end
```

There's no documentation for the class.

Also try http://apidock.com/rails -- this resource can be more helpful in general.

Comment: I am surprised to learn that the author gave this class a `:nodoc:
`.

Comment: @powerboy What explanation is needed? It's called this way: `raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"`. So, basically, it acts like a flag, not a source for some deep-digging.

Comment: I was not talking about this particular example. I was just thinking that sometimes Rails' authors seems to encourage users to read the source instead of the docs. For a language as flexible as Ruby and a framework that uses meta programming heavily, IDE coding assistance is useless mostly, therefore good documentation become very important.

Comment: @powerboy Rails is agile. You have to stay tuned in order to keep up. Reading the source is one of the requirements. But in this simple case the name is rather self-descriptive to put its doc in the tail of someone's todo-list.